# Windows changes symlink file when cloned from repo

Tags: windows, git, symlink

I have a git repository that contains some symlinks. This is usually used in a Linux environment.

However, when the repo is cloned to windows one of the symlinks changes, and thus building on windows using docker does not work.

The problem is quite simple. I have a symlink as such: `localtime -> /etc/localtime`

But when the file is cloned to a windows system it changes to : `localtime -> c:/etc/localtime`

This breaks the symlink when I try to make a build with it, as such building from windows doesn't work. The symlink in my Linux build will have changed to `/c/etc/localtime` instead of `/etc/localtime`

Git also doesn't seem to even register this change, as git status says all the files are up to date with master, even though this file is clearly different from the one in the repo

Is there any way to stop windows from automatically changing this file when its cloned?

Or is changing it to a be relative path the only option?

Comment: You could just remove symlink file from index or create a hook which can take OS into account

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but i fail to see how that would fix the actual issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Git or MSYS2, which is mistakenly resolving the target path. Symlinks that target the root of the opened path are supported. If "localtime" -> "\etc\localtime", then "C:\spam\localtime" resolves to "C:\etc\localtime". Mountpoints (aka junctions) act like hardlinks to a directory during path parsing, so "C:\SomeMountPoint\spam\localtime" also resolves to "C:\etc\localtime". OTOH, symlinks resolve the opened path to their target during path parsing. For example, if "SomeSymlink" -> "Z:\eggs", then "C:\SomeSymlink\spam\localtime" resolves to "Z:\etc\localtime".

Comment: I'd use WSL for this purpose, since it won't change the symlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove a symlink from index and add a script (bash, python or whatsoever) instead which generates a symlink.

Either you run this script by hand after clone or create a hook. Git handles text files much better as any other files, including symlinks.

If you use docker build, then you could setup to run this symlink-creation-step after clone anyway.

Comment: Yea, it will be removed from the repo and will them be created in the script that builds later on instead. Seems like the easiest fix